# Numpy slogdet computation error

Tags: numpy, determinants

There appears to be a major difference between numpy's slogdet and the exact result when computing the log determinant of Vanermonde matrix.

I compare against the exact log determinant, see eg [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant) for proof.

The minimal code to see this is:

```
A = np.power.outer(np.linspace(0,1,50),range(50))

print np.linalg.slogdet(A)[1]

s = 0
for v1 in np.linspace(0,1,50):
    for v2 in np.linspace(0,1,50):
        if v1>v2:
            s+= np.log(v1-v2)

print s
```

Which yeilds:

```
-1191.88408998
-1706.99560647
```

I was wondering if there was a more accurate log determinant implementation which I could use in this situation but also in non-Vandermonde matrix situation.

Comment: For N=10 the values match, as does `np.log(np.det(A))`.  It could be that by N=30, the `det(A)` is so small that even `slogdet` can't cope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sympy and mpmath like this:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as smp
import mpmath as mp

mp.mp.dps = 50 

linspace1 = list(map(smp.mpmath.mpf,np.linspace(0,1,50)))
A = np.power.outer(list(map(float,linspace1)),range(50))

first_print = smp.mpmath.mpf(np.linalg.slogdet(A)[1])
print(first_print)

s = 0
linspace2 = list(map(smp.mpmath.mpf,np.linspace(0,1,50)))
linspace3 = list(map(smp.mpmath.mpf,np.linspace(0,1,50)))
for v1 in linspace1:
    for v2 in linspace2:
        if v1>v2:
            s+= mp.log(v1-v2)

print(s)
```

#### RESULTS

```
first_print = -1178.272517342130186079884879291057586669921875

s = -1706.9956064674289001970168329846189154212781094939
```

Comment: Thanks but these two numbers are still off by roughly 50%, any ideas why?

Comment: @j__ what is the value expected aprox?

Comment: 1706.995 is the actual value using the formula specific to vandermonde matrices, but slogdet is roughly 50% off with 1706.272

Comment: @j__ I updated the answer again, let me know if those values are correct!

Comment: I don't think the OP is complaining about the iterative solution; it's the `slogdet` that's off.  It's faster but doesn't handle the larger array with very small determinant.  And `mpmath` does nothing for the `slogdet`.  That's calculated with a compiled LAPACK function using float64.

Comment: @hpaulj so there is no obvious solution? Thanks for the comments

Comment: You could try the [linear algebra routines of the mpmath library](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/matrices.html#the-eigenvalue-problem) instead the numpy ones.